# How to use multiple socket services in an asynchronous context manager?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

I've created a ConnectedSocket context manager for connecting and closing socket connections. However, when using create_task within the context manager to establish connections, the established connection immediately triggers aexit, and normal socket communication cannot proceed.

```
import asyncio
import socket
from asyncio import AbstractEventLoop
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Optional, Type
from typing import List


class ConnectedSocket:
    def __init__(self, server_socket):
        self._connection = None
        self._server_socket = server_socket

    async def __aenter__(self):
        print("Entering context manager, waiting for connection")
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        conn, addr = await loop.sock_accept(self._server_socket)
        conn.setblocking(False)  #
        self._connection = conn
        print("Accepted a connection")
        return self._connection

    async def __aexit__(self,
                        exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
                        exc_val: Optional[BaseException],
                        exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType]):
        print("Exiting context manager")
        self._connection.close()
        print("Closed connection")


class AsyncSocketServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop: AbstractEventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.tasks: List[asyncio.Task] = []

    async def create_server(self):
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  #
        server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
        server_socket.bind(server_address)
        server_socket.setblocking(False)
        server_socket.listen()
        await self.connection_listener(server_socket)

    async def connection_listener(self, server_socket):
        while True:
            async with ConnectedSocket(server_socket) as conn:
                task: asyncio.Task = asyncio.create_task(self.echo(conn))
                self.tasks.append(task)

                #Block
                # while data := await self.loop.sock_recv(conn, 1024):
                #     if data == b'exit\r\n':
                #         break
                #     print(data)

    async def echo(self, conn: socket) -> None:
        while data := await self.loop.sock_recv(conn, 1024):
            if data == b'exit\r\n':
                break
            print(data)

    def run(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.create_server())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = AsyncSocketServer()
    server.run()
```

telnet localhost 8000

```
Trying ::1... 
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused 
Trying 127.0.0.1... 
Connected to localhost. Escape
character is '^]'. 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "self._connection.close()" in **aexit** which caused the connection to close every time the ConnectedSocket popped out, so I removed it and it worked.